# Make yocto download more sources after unpacking

Tags: yocto

I have a recipe which references source A via the `SRC_URI` variable. However inside source A there is somewhere a link to another source B.
I'd like to let Yocto download and unpack source A. Then I would parse the URL for source B from source A and tell Yocto to go back to downloading and unpacking source B.
Is this possible?

The build process for source A would download source B itself, but I'd like Yocto to add source B to its `DL_DIR` to avoid downloading it again for the next build.

Comment: What you mean by "there is somewhere a link to another source B". What type of link? If Source A uses git submodule yocto could easily do that.

Comment: No, it's not sub-modules. Actually it's a URL in a JSON file.

Comment: You probably can make yocto do that by implementing something by your own, imho it is not a usual task

Comment: I understand that it is an unusual task. What do you means to implement something by my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bitbake's fetcher to fetch more sources.

It's important to note that the fetcher will still use the `SRCREV` variable, even if you append something like `;rev=xxx` to your URL. So you should set `SRCREV` to either `None` or `"AUTOINC"`.

```
python do_loadSources() {
  # Backup SRCREV
  mySrcRev = d.getVar('SRCREV')
  d.setVar('SRCREV', None)
  
  # Somehow determine source URL
  sourceUrl = ...

  # Create fetcher
  fetcher = bb.fetch2.Fetch([ sourceUrl ], d)

  # Download
  fetcher.download()

  # Get path of downloaded sources
  fetcher.localpath(sourceUrl)

  # Use the downloaded sources
  ...

  # Restore SRCREV
  d.setVar('SRCREV', mySrcRev)
}

addtask do_loadSources after do_configure before do_compile
```